# Writing an NSString to a Relative File

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, foundation

I'm getting strange behavior writing NSString and NSData objects to relative file paths. Here's an example:

```
NSString *string = @"I am a file!";
NSError *error =  nil;
NSString *fileName = @"text.txt";
BOOL written = [string writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

if (written) {
    NSLog(@"Successfully written to file.");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

When I run this I always get "Successfully written to file.", but the file is never there. Somehow the program thinks it was successful and no error is generated.

What am I doing wrong? (I'm on Mac OS X Lion)

Comment: If you're on iOS, you can only write within your app's document directory.

Comment: You can write in most directories under your application home, not just your document directory. You just can't write into your app bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This writes to the current directory. The default current directory when you run something under Xcode 4 is going to be `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<prodDir>/Build/Products/<configuration>`. You can override this using a Scheme. When you run a program from the commandline, then the current directory is whatever the current directory was when you ran the program. If you use Finder to launch the app, then the current directory will often be `/`.

In principle, it's fine to write the current working directory. It's very common to do this in command-line apps. So regarding @craig's comment about `writeToFile:` expecting an absolute path, I don't think that's really true. It expects and writes to a path. It doesn't care if it's absolute or relative. This is a Foundation class, and is just as useful in a command-line program as a GUI.

But in a GUI app, you should avoid relative paths. In principle, you could set the current directory and then write the file, but this is usually a bad idea in a large program since it's not thread safe (there is only one cwd for the whole program). And GUI apps tend to have somewhat unpredictable current directories, so it doesn't make for a good user experience.

But to the question of why you didn't get an error, it's because it probably successfully wrote it. You just didn't know where to look.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rob, and for the correction. It doesn't really care what kind of path is provided to it, and I hadn't considered the fact that he might be writing a non-GUI app. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter to the `writeToFile:` method (in your example) is a relative path, but you probably want to use an absolute path. Otherwise, the system will place your files relative to the current executable. When you're running inside Xcode, this might not be where you expect them to end up. (As Rob mentioned in his answer, this location is somewhat buried, and can change depending on which version of Xcode you're using.)

If you want to build up a directory path using `NSString` objects, I would recommend the `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` method:

```
...
NSString *directory = @"/Users/Mikael/Desktop";
NSString *filename = @"MyFile.txt";

NSString *fullPath = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
...
```

Note that this method will take care of making sure your slashes are well-formed.

Comment: I know that absolute file paths are better. But I was trying it and it wasn't generating an error even though it wasn't working.

Comment: I didn't know that writeToFile: expected only an absolute path though, thanks.

Comment: How do you know it wasn't working? Did you check to see if a file exists at **/text.txt**? And it's not that absolute file paths are *better*, it's that you should NEVER really be using a relative path with a method that expects an absolute one. Best case scenario your file will end up where you don't expect it, worst case scenario you'll start blowing away other files. Note that the **writeToFile:** method will blindly overwrite the file (if any) that exists at that path. Please be careful.

Comment: Yes, I checked the folder that the source files were and also did a Spotlight search.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding the issue here - your application is not running from inside the folder where your source files reside. Otherwise, how would you expect this folder to exist when running from a **.app** bundle on an end-user's machine?

Comment: Just got the Idea of checking the folder the executable was in, the file was there. Sorry about that. Thanks for all the tips, craig.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSFileManager * fm = [NSFileManager new];
NSString * dirPath = [fm currentDirectoryPath];
NSString * absPath = [dirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.file"];
[fm release];
```

keep in mind that currentDirectoryPath reflects your programs working directory until you change it with `-changeCurrentDirectoryPath:`, the programs working directory can be different depending on how it was launched, and can't be relied upon.